# Given the choice is it better to have somekeywords.com, somekeyword2.com or myotherwebsite/some-keywords, myotherwebsite/some-keywords

Tags: seo, keywords

Hello
I'm thinking of creating a family of websites which use the same engine, but target different topics.
Given the choice is it better to have somekeywords.com, somekeywords2.com or myotherwebsite/some-keywords, myotherwebsite/some-keywords2.
For example:
stackexchange.com/stackoverflow
stackexchange.com/askubuntu
instead of
stackoverflow.com
askubuntu.com
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The best is the shortest and the easiest address to be remember by your users.

By my side, my favorite practice is usage of sub-domains:

- undersite.parent.invalid
- undersite2.parent.invalid

BUT, a lot of users want absolutely put WWW before when I stated orally (for example, by phone), so, I always make an other sub-domains like this with redirection just for this purpose:

- www.undersite.parent.invalid

  - [303 See Other](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.4): undersite.parent.invalid
- www.undersite2.parent.invalid

  - [303 See Other](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.4): undersite2.parent.invalid